# Preview for revision?

Tags: plugins, hooks, revisions, previews

Is this possible: to allow admins to preview revisions from revision history, either with a plugin or hook?

I would like to allow the admin to view post and page revisions, without having to restore them. I already tried this plugin: https://rtcamp.com/blog/easily-preview-wordpress-post-page-revisions-before-restoring/, but it only seems to work for default templates.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This plugin is pretty helpful: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/revisionary/

Comment: Thank you so much @admcfajn that's exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to add it as an answer below.

Comment: An update for posterity - this plugin doesn't seem to work with templates that use acf flexible content..